# How can I find monotonicity intervals? v18

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

We have $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $F(x)=x\int _0^x (1+\cos(t)) \, dt$ and we neeed to find monotonicity intervals and I don't know how... 
Here is what I try to do: $$F'(x)=\int _0^x (1+\cos(t)) \, dt+x\cdot f(x)=x+\sin(x)+x\cdot f(x),$$ and after it how can I find the sign for $F'(x)$?

Comment: Is there something wrong with doing the integral first?

Comment: after it, I wil equal the result with 0 ?

Comment: how can I find the sign for $F'(x)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ F(x) = x \int_0^{x} (1+\cos{t}) \, dt = x[ t + \sin{t} ]_0^x = x^2+x\sin{x}. $$
Now differentiate,
$$ F'(x) = 2x+x\cos{x}+\sin{x}. $$
You then have to find the zeros of this function. It is odd, so there is a zero at $x=0$. In fact, that's all, because for $x>0$, $x(2+\cos{x})>x$, and $\sin{x}<x$, so they can't cancel to zero.

---

To do it without doing the integral, note that the function is even. For $x>0$, the integrand is non-negative, and the integral is then positive and increasing since the function starts off positive. $x$ is also increasing, and a product of two increasing functions is increasing. Lastly, since the function is even, it is decreasing for $x<0$.

Comment: Chappers I don't understand the final part, how we can find the sign for $2x+xcosx+sinx$ ? where is minus and where is plus? and why they can't cancel to zero?

Comment: For $x>0$, write it as $x(2+\cos{x})+\sin{x}>x+\sin{x}$, which is $>0$ as $x>|\sin{x}|$. For $x<0$, since the $x(2+\cos{x})+\sin{x}$ is odd, the sign is opposite.

Comment: and why they can't cancel to zero? because $F′(0)=0$

Comment: Because $2+\cos{x} \geqslant 1$, but $x > |\sin{x}|$: equality is not achieved in the latter except at $x=0$.

Comment: you say it is odd when x<0, what did you led to say it?

Comment: Well, it's odd. You can see this because it's the sum of $\sin{x}$, which is odd, and the product of an even function, $2+\cos{x}$, and an odd one, $x$. Odd + even * odd = odd.